# Generating thumbnails from multiple videos on Desktop, using ffmpeg, or something similar

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, video-capture

Hi guys this is a long shot but here goes...

I basically have what I mentioned in the title running on my server.  When I upload a video ffmpeg decomplies it and gives me screenshots, then I pick a screenshot that I want to use for that video. Currently, my server can process 3 videos at a time. The down side is that this uses up A LOT of the server processing power. :(

Is there a way, or a program, that can process several video at a time and generate me screenshots on my Desktop? If this is possible then I can just use my spare computer here to process everything then upload the screenshots/video to my server.

This is what I basically have running now on the server. [kayweb.com.au/blogs/Web-Development/Generating-screenshots-using-FFmpeg](http://kayweb.com.au/blogs/Web-Development/Generating-screenshots-using-FFmpeg)

Something like this, But this thumbnail generator puts everything into one image. I need to be able to choose with thumbnail I want to use.
http://www.tothepc.com/archives/make-movie-caps-screenshots-with-free-video-thumbnails-maker/

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How would you pick the particular video frame to use as a thumbnail?  Is picking a random frame good enough, or do you want to pick a frame that is most representative of the particular video?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what is the problem? It seems ffmpeg is helping you, but is too much time consuming. If the problem is the number of files that ffmpeg generates, you probably can limit it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with getting multiple thumbs is the time. So far I have not been able to get multiple thumbs from a single scan, so it means I have to scan three times for three images.

In my case I took the video time in seconds then got the the three images from 1/4, 1/2 and 3/4. But for long videos this is far too slow, even using ffmpeg's offset value. It is better if you can to select from the first 10-20 seconds into the video.

So I start with a pre-process, this scans the images at the time of the file search then any that haven't got a thumb created it creates one from a few seconds into the video, that is a quick process and in a thread of it's own isn't really noticeable, unless there are a lot of videos needing an icon, so a first run will be slow.

Then as with the functions form, if the thumb isn't any good I allow the selection from my 3 thumbs which are generated on the fly. In my case I used MDI so I could marry various parts of a media suite together. So the part below is a form on it's own, the file list 'videoList', has been filled when the user selected a directory in another form.

Just for completeness I will include my MediaItem and MediaType enums.

Ignore the way I have named my temporary files, I am still working on that because I will be marrying it with a service later which will supply the name. You can get problems using the same files in C# that were just created or modified in an external process, so you do need some clever file use convention.

```
    public partial class ThumbSelector : Form
{
    public List<MediaItem> videoList = new List<MediaItem>();
    private Random ra = new Random();
    int iCount = 1;

    public ThumbSelector()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void FillList()
    {
        if(videoList.Count() < 1)
            return;
        //only get mp4 files
        var videosOnly = from n in videoList
                      where n.mainType == MediaMainType.MMT_VIDEO
                      select n;
        lbVideoList.Items.Clear();
        foreach (MediaItem mi in videosOnly)
        {
            lbVideoList.Items.Add(mi.shortName);
        }
    }

    private void lbVideoList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(lbVideoList.SelectedItems.Count < 1)
            return;
        CreateThumbs(lbVideoList.SelectedItems[0].ToString());
    }

    private void CreateThumbs(string fShortName)
    {
        string sourceVideoName;
        int sourceLength = 0;
        int quarter = 0;
        int half = 0;
        int threequarter = 0;
        string destDir = @"C:\Users\robert\dwhelper\VideoIcons";

        string ffPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\ffmpeg.exe";

        var sname = (from n in videoList
                    where n.shortName == fShortName
                     select n).First();
        sourceVideoName = sname.fullName;
        sourceLength = GetVideoLength(ffPath, sourceVideoName);

        quarter = sourceLength / 4;
        half = sourceLength / 2;
        threequarter = quarter * 3;
        Image im1;
        Image im2;
        Image im3;
        string n1;
        string n2;
        string n3;


        while (File.Exists(string.Concat(destDir, @"\", "x1_", iCount.ToString(), ".jpg")))
        {
            ++iCount;
        }
        n1 = string.Concat("x1_", iCount.ToString(), ".jpg");
        ++iCount;
        while (File.Exists(string.Concat(destDir, @"\", "x2_", iCount.ToString(), ".jpg")))
        {
            ++iCount;
        }
        n2 = string.Concat("x2_", iCount.ToString(), ".jpg");
        ++iCount;
        while (File.Exists(string.Concat(destDir, @"\", "x3_", iCount.ToString(), ".jpg")))
        {
            ++iCount;
        }
        n3 = string.Concat("x3_", iCount.ToString(), ".jpg");

        pic1.Image = null;
        pic2.Image = null;
        pic3.Image = null;


        CreateThumbs(sname, quarter, n1);
        im1 = Image.FromFile(string.Concat(destDir, @"\", n1));
        pic1.Image = im1;
        CreateThumbs(sname, half, n2);
        im2 = Image.FromFile(string.Concat(destDir, @"\", n2));
        pic2.Image = im2;
        CreateThumbs(sname, threequarter, n3);
        im3 = Image.FromFile(string.Concat(destDir, @"\", n3));
        pic3.Image = im3;

    }

    private void CreateThumbs(MediaItem mi, int timeIn, string outName)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        Process pth;
        string destDir = @"C:\Users\robert\dwhelper\VideoIcons";
        string sourceFile;
        string destFile;
        string ffPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\ffmpeg.exe";
        string strCommand;
        string fullCommand;
        string[] ssplit;

        sourceFile = mi.fullName;
        ssplit = mi.shortName.Split('.');
        destFile = string.Concat(destDir, "\\", outName);

        strCommand = string.Concat(
            " -i \"", sourceFile, "\" -r 1 -ss ", timeIn.ToString(), " -t 00:00:01 -f image2 \"", destFile, "\"");

        fullCommand = string.Concat(ffPath, strCommand);

        pth = new Process();
        pth.StartInfo.FileName = ffPath;
        pth.StartInfo.Arguments = strCommand;
        pth.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pth.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        pth.Start();
        pth.WaitForExit();

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

    }

    private int GetVideoLength(string ffmpeg, string sourceFile)
    {
        //exec('start C:\Inetpub\ffmpeg\ffmpeg -i "D:/Jaime-flex.wmv" 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | cut -d " " -f 4 - | sed s/,//', $output);
        string result = "";
        string strCommand = string.Concat(
                " -i \"", sourceFile, "\" 2>");
        Process pth = new Process();
        pth.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpeg;
        pth.StartInfo.Arguments = strCommand;
        pth.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pth.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pth.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pth.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pth.Start();


        pth.WaitForExit();
        //result = pth.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        //result = pth.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        string str = "";
        string[] ssplit;
        char[] splitChars = new char[] { '.', ' ' };
        int seconds = 0;
        while (!pth.StandardError.EndOfStream)
        {
            str = pth.StandardError.ReadLine();
            if (str.Contains("Duration"))
            {
                ssplit = str.Split(splitChars);
                seconds = GetSeconds(ssplit[3]);
            }
        }
        return seconds;
    }

    private int GetSeconds(string p)
    {
        string[] ssplit = p.Split(':');
        int ho = Convert.ToInt32(ssplit[0]) * 120;
        int mi = Convert.ToInt32(ssplit[1]) * 60;
        int se = Convert.ToInt32(ssplit[2]);

        return ho + mi + se;
    }

}
public class MediaItem
{
    public string shortName { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public string iconName { get; set; }
    public MediaMainType mainType { get; set; }
    public MediaSubType subType { get; set; }
    public long length { get; set; }
}
public enum MediaMainType
{
    MMT_VIDEO = 0, MMT_IMAGE, MMT_ICON, MMT_NOTMEDIA
}
public enum MediaSubType
{
    MST_JPG = 0, MST_GIF, MST_BMP, MST_PNG, MST_MP4, MST_WMV, MST_FLV, MST_NOTMEDIA
3
```